# Prepared statements with parameterized column names don't work

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I have problem using prepared statements in my project. I've created a class named DB and inside this class I have a function called "where" and in this form it does not work:

```
public function where($table_name, $key, $value) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE :key = :value ORDER BY id DESC");
        $stmt->execute(array(":key" => $key, ":value" => $value));
        return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? $stmt : false; 
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but when I change the function to just work with one placeholder it works! Why this happens?

```
public function where($table_name, $key, $value) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE $key = :value ORDER BY id DESC");
        $stmt->execute(array(":value" => $value));
        return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? $stmt : false; 
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use placeholders for field names in PDO, only for value parameters.

See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have fields in prepared statements. You can however insert it using `PDO::quote`:

```
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE " . $this->connection->quote($key) . " = :value ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe PDO::quote doesn't work well for field names either. As a first step, try without the quote() call, as in `$stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE " . $key . " = :value ORDER BY id DESC");`

Comment: Without the quote() method it words but when using quote() method, it doesn't.